# Formatting with out losing any data?

Tags: boot

I tired to format my PC whit out losing any data 
So that I wan,t to help me how to do that
How I can format my PC with out losing any data ?

Comment: [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/66378/355310)? What exactly are you trying to do? Reinstall the OS maybe? What is your OS then? What research have you done and what have you tried so far? Please respond by [edit]ing the question.

Comment: Short answer is you cannot.

Answer (score 3):

Formatting your "PC" typically refers to formatting the hard disk drive within the device. By definition, this action of formatting is explicitly the action of erasing the data on the drive.

If you wish to not lose any data, it is necessary to create a backup of this data to an external device such as another (portable) hard drive or to a USB flash drive of sufficient capacity.

If you are sufficiently skilled, you can use a utility such as gparted (bootable) and partition the existing drive, format the new partition, reboot the computer, transfer your data to the new partition, reboot gparted, format the old partition, re-install the operating system and transfer the data back (or leave it as is.)

This is excessive and using a backup device is far simpler.